# Fix the position of image in an HTML string

Tags: html, ios

I have an HTML string which i load in an UIWebView. This HTML string comes from an RSS feed's content and in most cases its formatting is not clean (spacing b/w image and text is very less.. image is positioned randomly). I want to make this HTML in a proper formatted way such that the image is always on the left (like Flipboard's detail screen). Is this possible

Answer (score 1):

get the image source urlLink and build the html string as follows and then load the htmlString in to webView.

```
htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><span style='width:300px; margin-right:10px; float:left; border-bottom:1px solid #22242a; color:#22242a; padding-bottom:5px;'><img src='%@' width='300' height='200' align='left' style='margin:0px 25px 15px 0px; padding:1px; border:1px solid #ccc;'> %@</span></html>",imageLink,caption]
```

Answer (score 0):

if possible try to avoid uiwebview in your native application. ( however there are certain scenarios where it's recommended ).

You should fetch only data from server and display as your Application UI design.
If possible try to get the url of image in the RSS feed and fetch it using native API's for displaying in your view. This way you will have more control over your application.

-- Vishal